# (Postgre)SQL Update query does not return

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a simple update query (on two large tables) which does never finish.

```
UPDATE transit_edge te1 SET dates_to_add =
(   SELECT ARRAY_AGG(date)
    FROM transit_edge te2 LEFT OUTER JOIN calendar_dates cd2 ON (te2.service_id = cd2.service_id AND cd2.exception_type = 1)
    WHERE te2.transit_edge_id = te1.transit_edge_id
);
```

If I only run the inner query with a given id, I get the correct result.

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(date) 
FROM transit_edge te2 LEFT OUTER JOIN calendar_dates cd2 ON (te2.service_id = cd2.service_id AND cd2.exception_type = 1) 
WHERE te2.transit_edge_id = te1.transit_edge_id AND te1.transit_edge_id = 282956
```

The table count is rather high:

```
select count(*) from transit_edge;
count
---------
9187885

select count(*) from calendar_dates;
count
----------
10025969
```

I also updated the postgresql.conf to enable larger memory usage.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RESOURCE USAGE (except WAL)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Memory -

shared_buffers = 2GB   
work_mem = 200MB   
checkpoint_segments = 3
max_connections = 100 
maintenance_work_mem = 64MB
```

I ran the inner query with a limit of 100 and got the following error message

```
ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 1073741824
```

Any help is kindly appreciated!
Daniel

Comment: `EXPLAIN` output for the query that never finishes?

Comment: Tried that, but I also get no output for explain.

Comment: No output for `EXPLAIN`? Without `ANALYZE`? That suggests it's getting stuck in planning, and that shouldn't happen. Exact PostgreSQL version from `SELECT version()`?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2, 64-bit

Comment: ... and a simple `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...` hangs indefinitely? Is there anything relevant in `pg_locks`? Is the postgres backend (identified by running `SELECT pg_backend_pid()` before running the `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...`) using 100% CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like:

```
UPDATE transit_edge te1 SET dates_to_add =
(   SELECT ARRAY_AGG(date)
    FROM calendar_dates cd2
    WHERE te1.service_id = cd2.service_id AND cd2.exception_type = 1
);
```

Comment: Is there any way to see if something actually happens, or do I have to wait till the complete query is finished?

Comment: @DanielGerber You can limit the outer (`UPDATE`) query to a small subset of id's (`WHERE te1.transit_edge_id in (1,2,3, etc)`) to check the results. If the results are OK - proceed with full query.

Comment: @CraigRinger It may not help if the query is doing something stupid (like a cartesian product because of a missing join condition)

Comment: This query seems to return with results. But is this really the same query with respect to the left outer join?